# How does IntelliJ automatically deploy the webapp in tomcat?

Tags: java, servlets, intellij-idea, tomcat7

How does IntelliJ automatically deploy the webapp in tomcat?
Just wondering as after the webapp has been deployed and run, there are no traces of the web app in the tomcat folder. (Not even the servlet classes' files).
Does it create those file and delete straight after execution?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this link - http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Creating_a_simple_Web_application_and_deploying_it_to_Tomcat

Comment: Most likely it uses another folder, possibly even the build directory directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ is deploying the exploded WAR which exists in your compilation target directory (for my project, it's `target` - it could be `out` for yours, depends on if you're using Maven or some other dependency management application), in the process explained [at this Wiki link](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Creating_a_simple_Web_application_and_deploying_it_to_Tomcat).

So, the artifact always exists in your `target` or `out` directory.  If it *didn't* exist, then Tomcat would pitch a fit.