# attempting to run a spring-mvc project in intelliJ

Tags: spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I've cloned a spring-mvc project and was hoping to get it running. First time working on a project like this and could use help. I was told, I should be able to run the project and have a test environment on localhost. Instead, I only have an option to debug. I've added spring for Framework support, maybe I need to add something else?

[run test image http://snag.gy/AySh6.jpg](http://snag.gy/AySh6.jpg)

here are some images of my project structure, in case it helps

modules

[module image http://snag.gy/94Cnb.jpg](http://snag.gy/94Cnb.jpg)

libraries

[project library image http://snag.gy/znR7x.jpg](http://snag.gy/znR7x.jpg)

SDK's

[project sdk image http://snag.gy/cI4Wj.jpg](http://snag.gy/cI4Wj.jpg)

**edit**: added image for `add run configuration` menu

[configuration menu http://snag.gy/piyzz.jpg](http://snag.gy/piyzz.jpg)

run configuration menu

Comment: Thanks for the images, but they're not really relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the right-click popup menu gives only options to run tests. You have to create a new [run configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html) using the `Run` item from the main menu, or the specific run area on the main toolbar.

Comment: I'm looking at the run configuration menu and when I click 'Add configuration' I see a dropdown menu. Should I set up the application to use tomcat? I've added an image of my options

Comment: just found the answer to my second question. I do indeed use tomcat http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Getting+Started+with+Spring+MVC,+Hibernate+and+JSON

Answer (score 2):

You need to deploy the webapp to a tomcat.

You can check this issue for more info:
[Intelli tomcatJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21960722/how-does-intellij-automatically-deploy-the-webapp-in-tomcat)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a run configuration for your server and configure the webapp to be deployed to it. Spring mvc is meant to be run on a server, and the client is, usually, a browser.