# How does intellij map war to webapps during deployment to tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, deployment, web-applications

I want to know how intellij maps an artifact created in the 'out' folder to the webapps of tomcat.

My project is deployed successfully and I am able to see it in the browser. But when I check the webapps folder of the tomcat, I am not able to see my app folder.

I wanted to know how is intellij deploying to tomcat without moving the files to the webapps folder.

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21960722/how-does-intellij-automatically-deploy-the-webapp-in-tomcat) that is similar to mine but the answer does not mention the process.

I read about the [different ways](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html) that tomcat deploys but couldn't get how exactly intellij is doing it.

Comment: They do it the other way around by changing the tomcat config to reference the webapp in your build.

Comment: My answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/7702077/104891 explains how it works. What specific problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Is the 'temporary directory' that you mentioned in the answer in the link, the 'out' directory where the artifact is created?

Comment: The temporary directory would be under the System directory: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html#system-directory where IntelliJ IDEA places the modified Tomcat configuration and it's used for CATALINA_BASE. The modified configuration instructs Tomcat to deploy the artifact directly from the artifact output directory that you can see at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/artifacts.html. Does it make sense?